# How to format a CV / Resume so that it can be parsed by automatic resume uploaders?

Tags: cv, markup

Many job sites do not accept a PDF resume; they require me to fill in their custom fields. Other sites will attempt to parse a PDF into pre-defined fields but this process does a poor job of recognizing the field contents.

Is there a way that I can format my resume so that it parses well for job sites? Perhaps by including specific XML tags?

Comment: This cannot be answered without posting link to a site that you're concerned about. As well, if you achieved some particular observations about the site behaviour, it would be nice if you added it to your question.

Comment: @tohecz the feature is ubiquitous among sites that host a resume, although implementation probably varies: here are some examples: [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/using-linkedIn/ULI/505676-15808563), [usajobs.gov](http://www.epa.gov/careers/apply2.html), and [monster.com](http://resume.monster.com/)

Comment: Well, we'd really need to know what those parsers are looking for in a pdf, then we might be able to say if and how it can be implemented with *TeX. The question how these parsers work and what they're looking for would be off-topic for this site.

Comment: @doncherry I am looking for something generic, although I don't know how the sites work. They seem to try to extract information like /education/institution/years/degree and /job/position/years/description, but i don't know the mechanics. Perhaps this question could be migrated? In the meantime, I will consider asking a question about how these works somewhere like superuser.

Comment: @David You can flag your own question for moderator attention and explain the migration issue. I'm not 100% sure if [su] is the right page, though. [webapps.se] might be an idea.

Comment: @doncherry I asked a similar question on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39107/8590)

Comment: @David Let us know if you get answers over there. We should close this one as off-topic then.

Comment: @doncherry I was thinking that I could modify this once I learn the requirements; I could also open a new question.